# Getting error in loading json from static file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I have D3 api for showing link analysis i.e some datas  are interconnected with one another.

In my api i can manage that,it is showing the relationship when i write them in hard coded in the jsp file when i write the api.

But Now i have to load the data from an External json file using `d3.json("Link.json",error,data)` but when i do that the page does show me anythihg.

Here is my code i am posting what i have done and what i am trying to do...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <style>

        /* CSS Document */
        .link10 {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 2px;             
        }

        .link1 {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }

        .nodetext {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .node.type1 {
            fill: #800000;
        }

        .node.type4 {
            fill: #000000;
            stroke: #1695A3;
            stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        .node.type5 {
            fill: #0000A0;
            size: 20px;
        }

        .node.type7 {
            fill: #008000;
            size: 40px;
        }

        image.circle {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .fadein {
            display: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .rectD {
            background-color: #000000;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px
        }

        .rectL {
            background-color: #000000;
            width: 90px;
            height: 30px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var data = {
            "nodes" : [ {
                    "name" : "JEET",
                    "full_name" : "Yahoo",
                    "type" : 4,
                    "slug" : "www.yahoo.com",
                    "entity" : "company",
                    "img_hrefD" : "",
                    "img_hrefL" : ""
                }, {
                    "name" : "SATISH",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name" : "RAHUL",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name": "DANIEL",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },

                {
                    "name" : "Offnet",
                    "full_name":"Yandex",
                    "type":5,
                    "slug":"www.yandex.com",
                    "entity":"company",
                    "img_hrefD":"",
                    "img_hrefL":""

                }, {
                    "name" : "Onnet",
                    "full_name":"Yandex",
                    "type":7,
                    "slug":"www.yandex.com",
                    "entity":"company",
                    "img_hrefD":"",
                    "img_hrefL":""
                }, {
                    "name" : "Desc4",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },

                {
                    "name" : "SHYAM",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name" : "PETER",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name" : "ALEX",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name" : "MURFY",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }, {
                    "name" : "JENIFER",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },{
                    "name" : "Subho",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },{
                    "name" : "abc",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "jfyh",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "flid",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "gerard",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "hfud",
                    "type" : 1,
                    "slug" : "",
                    "entity" : "description"
                }
            ],

            "links" : [ {
                    "source" : 0,
                    "target" : 4,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                }, {
                    "source" : 0,
                    "target" : 5,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                }, {
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 6,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                },

                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 7,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                }, {
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 2,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                }, {
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 3,
                    "value" : 1,
                    "distance" : 5
                },

                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 8,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                }, {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 9,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                }, {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 10,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                }, {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 11,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },

                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 12,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                }, {
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 1,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },{
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 13,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },
                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 14,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },
                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 15,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },
                {
                    "source" : 5,
                    "target" : 16,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                },
                {
                    "source" : 4,
                    "target" : 17,
                    "value" : 10,
                    "distance" : 6
                }
            ]
        };

        var w = 560, h = 500, radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0,312000 ])
        .range([ "10", "50" ]);

        var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr(
        "height", h);

        vis.append("marker")
        .attr("id", "arrowhead")
        .attr("refX", 6 + 2) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
        .attr("refY", 2)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 4)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead






        //d3.json(data, function(json) {
        var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
        data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
            return (d.distance * 10);
        })
        //.friction(0.5)
        .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();

        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(data.links).enter().append(
        "svg:line").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "link" + d.value + "";
        }).attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
            if (d.value == 10 || d.value==1) {
                return "url(#arrowhead)"
            } else {
                return " "
            }
            ;
        });

        function openLink() {
            return function(d) {
                var url = "";
                if (d.slug != "") {
                    url = d.slug
                } else if(d.type == 2) {
                    url = "clients/" + d.slug
                } else if(d.type == 3) {
                    url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                }
                window.open("//" + url)
            }
        }

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
        "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);

        node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "node type" + d.type
        }).attr("r", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "description") {
                return 10
            } else {
                return 18
            }
        })


        node.append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
            return "nodetext title_" + d.name
        }).attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").style("font-size", "10px").attr(
        "text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white").text(
        function(d) {
            if (d.entity != "description") {
                return d.name
            }
        });

        node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "description") {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "15px")

            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                var asdf = d3.select(this);
                asdf.select('text').remove();

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                    return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name
                }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size", "5px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");

                asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                    return d.snd_name
                }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("transform",
                "translate(0, 12)").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size", "5px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");
            } else {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "15px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "90px").attr("x",
                "-46px").attr("y", "-36.5px").attr("xlink:href",
                function(d) {
                    return d.img_hrefL
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 28)

            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 15)
            }
        });

        node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "10px")
            } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
                ///////////////////////////
                // CHANGE
                ///////////////////////////

                d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

                //d3.select(this).select('text')
                d3.select(this).append('text').text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }).style("font-size", "14px").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                .attr("class", "nodetext").transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "10px")

            } else {
                d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                .style("font-size", "10px")
            }

            if (d.entity == "company") {
                d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "70px").attr("x",
                "-36px").attr("y", "-36px").attr("xlink:href",
                function(d) {
                    return d.img_hrefD
                });
            }

            if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

                d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                .attr("r", 18)
            }

        });

        node.on("mouseover", fade(.4, "red")).on("mouseout", fade(1));

        var linkedByIndex = {};
        data.links.forEach(function(d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
        });

        function isConnected(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index]
                || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]
                || a.index == b.index;
        }

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
        });


        function getConnected(cn, d, level) {
            node.each(function(o) {
                if(isConnected(d, o) && cn.indexOf(o) == -1) {
                    cn.push(o);
                    if(level > 0) getConnected(cn, o, level-1);
                };
            });

            return cn;
        }


        function fade(opacity,color) {
            return function(d) {

                node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                    this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                    return thisOpacity;
                });

                link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                })

                .style("stroke", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000" ;
                });
            };

        }
        //});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that is working ....

Here i have made the json file
Link.json

```
 {

    "nodes" : [ {
        "name" : "JEET",
        "full_name" : "Yahoo",
        "type" : 4,
        "slug" : "www.yahoo.com",
        "entity" : "company",
        "img_hrefD" : "",
        "img_hrefL" : ""
    }, {
        "name" : "SATISH",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name" : "RAHUL",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name": "DANIEL",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },

    {
        "name" : "Offnet",
        "full_name":"Yandex",
        "type":5,
        "slug":"www.yandex.com",
        "entity":"company",
        "img_hrefD":"",
        "img_hrefL":""

    }, {
        "name" : "Onnet",
        "full_name":"Yandex",
        "type":7,
        "slug":"www.yandex.com",
        "entity":"company",
        "img_hrefD":"",
        "img_hrefL":""
    }, {
        "name" : "Desc4",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },

    {
        "name" : "SHYAM",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name" : "PETER",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name" : "ALEX",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name" : "MURFY",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }, {
        "name" : "JENIFER",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },{
        "name" : "Subho",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },{
        "name" : "abc",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },
    {
        "name" : "jfyh",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },
    {
        "name" : "flid",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },
    {
        "name" : "gerard",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    },
    {
        "name" : "hfud",
        "type" : 1,
        "slug" : "",
        "entity" : "description"
    }
    ],

    "links" : [ {
        "source" : 0,
        "target" : 4,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    }, {
        "source" : 0,
        "target" : 5,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    }, {
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 6,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    },

    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 7,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    }, {
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 2,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    }, {
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 3,
        "value" : 1,
        "distance" : 5
    },

    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 8,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    }, {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 9,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    }, {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 10,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    }, {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 11,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },

    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 12,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    }, {
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 1,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },{
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 13,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },
    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 14,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },
    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 15,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },
    {
        "source" : 5,
        "target" : 16,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" : 6
    },
    {
        "source" : 4,
        "target" : 17,
        "value" : 10,
        "distance" :6
    }
    ]

}
```

Here what i have changed in the api  to load from Link.json

```
  d3.json("Link.json", function(error,data) {
        var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
        data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
            return (d.distance * 10);
        })
        //.friction(0.5)
        .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();
```

this is what i have done please help me to do this.. and also i am getting the error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined ..please somebody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json):

> The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs.

I suspect you are not hosting the `Links.json` file along with the `index.html`.

Also, I think you have an extra wrapping with `data` in your JSON which will become a problem once the browser can fetch the `Link.json` file.

Comment: ok i am cutting the data part from the json and posting back see if it is correct

Comment: @lucifer Is the `Link.json` file accessible from the browser?

Comment: @lucifer Also, your are using `v2.9` of D3, where, I think the order of arguments was reversed in the `d3.json` callback. Try `function (data, error)` or upgrading to `v3.*`.